# Getting Fatal error when calling MPI_Reduce inside a loop

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have a problem in this part of code (which is common between the tasks):

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // some code
    MPI_Reduce(&res, &mn, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // some code
}
```

This is working fine, but for large values of `m` I get this error:

```
    Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce: Other MPI error, error stack:
    PMPI_Reduce(1198).........................: MPI_Reduce(sbuf=008FFC80, rbuf=008FFC8C, count=1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
    MPIR_Reduce(764)..........................:
    MPIR_Reduce_binomial(207).................:
    MPIC_Send(41).............................:
    MPIC_Wait(513)............................:
    MPIDI_CH3i_Progress_wait(215).............: an error occurred while handling an event returned by MPIDU_Sock_Wait()
    MPIDI_CH3I_Progress_handle_sock_event(436):
    MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_EagerShortSend(306)..: Failed to allocate memory for an unexpected message. 261895 unexpected messages queued.
    
    job aborted:
    rank: node: exit code[: error message]
    0: AmirDiab: 1
    1: AmirDiab: 1
    2: AmirDiab: 1: Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce: Other MPI error, error stack:
    PMPI_Reduce(1198).........................: MPI_Reduce(sbuf=008FFC80, rbuf=008FFC8C, count=1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
    MPIR_Reduce(764)..........................:
    MPIR_Reduce_binomial(207).................:
    MPIC_Send(41).............................:
    MPIC_Wait(513)............................:
    MPIDI_CH3i_Progress_wait(215).............: an error occurred while handling an event returned by MPIDU_Sock_Wait()
    MPIDI_CH3I_Progress_handle_sock_event(436):
    MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_EagerShortSend(306)..: Failed to allocate memory for an unexpected message. 261895 unexpected messages queued.
    3: AmirDiab: 1
```

Any advice?

Comment: `MPI_INT` is not a match for `bool` (use `MPI_CXX_BOOL` in C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598517/how-to-send-boolean-datatype-through-mpi-c/57600337)

Comment: thanks for your comment, `bool` is actually `int`,  I've defined bool as int as I noted by writing `typedef int bool;` in my code. I'm sorry if this make confusing. I'll edit the question :)

Comment: The root cause can be a consequence of a previous memory corruption. Can you edit your question with a [mcve] ?

Comment: What is the return value of MPI_Reduce?

Comment: I'm new to MPI and don't know how reduce actually work between tasks, do you mean that I should avoid using `MPI_Reduce` inside loops? @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: I mean you should write a minimal program that
1) evidence the issue
2) can be compiled
A snippet is unfortunately not helpful here.

Comment: it returns `0` until the error occur .. after that I can't print the returned value @kungjohan

Comment: note the error message `Failed to allocate memory for an unexpected message. 261895 unexpected messages queued`. That either suggests a memory leak in your program, or an internal control flow issue. A workaround worth trying is to `MPI_Barrier(...)` every nth iterations (`10` should work but with a performance penalty, `100` should be a bit faster if it works)

Comment: You are right. The error disappeared but with slowing as you mentioned. Thank youu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overtaxing MPI with your communication pattern. Note the `261895 unexpected messages queued` error message. That's quite a lot of messages. As MPI tries to send data for small messages (like your single-element reductions) eagerly, running hundreds of thousands of `MPI_Reduce` calls in a loop can lead to resource exhaustion when too many messages are in flight.

If possible, try to re-arrange your algorithm so that you handle all `m` elements in a single reduction instead of iterating over them:

```
int* res = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
int* ms  = malloc(m * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    ms[i] = /* ... */
}

MPI_Reduce(res, ms, m, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, you can add `MPI_Barrier()` calls every so often inside the loop to limit the number of outstanding messages.

Comment: Great!! this solved my problem with a good performance. Thanks for your answer.